# How do I find a window at a certain point on the screen for screenshot/screen-recording purposes?

Tags: cocoa, winapi, x11, macos-carbon, window-managers

I'm looking for a way to do what the equivalent of WindowFromPoint and GetWindowRect do, in Carbon/Cocoa and X11.

WindowFromPoint - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28VS.85%29.aspx
GetWindowRect - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628921/find-window-at-location-using-carbon-and-carbon-problems-in-64-bit-applications

Comment: What do you intend to do with the retrieved window "handle".  The window manager on carbon/cocoa keeps a lot of data structures per-process for windows so the only real way to get meaningful access to another window on OS X is via the accessibility apis.

Comment: Well, I am developing screenshot and screen recording apps - I want to use the handle to determine the bounding rectangle of the window, and then use the coordinates of the window to capture a bitmap of that area of the screen and save it to a file or encode it into a video stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am developing screenshot and screen recording apps …

Use [Quartz Window Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Introduction.html).

> I want to … determine the bounding rectangle of the window, and then use the coordinates of the window to capture a bitmap of that area of the screen …

*Definitely* use Quartz Window Services.

Incidentally, one of its features is that you can capture a window in isolation, without anything that may be in front of it or behind it. You don't need to get its rectangle when doing this.

> … and save it to a file …

Use [CGImageDestination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/).

> … or encode it into a video stream.

That part I'm not sure about. [The sample code on the matter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/OpenGLScreenCapture/) (which, as its name says, uses OpenGL for the actual capturing) uses the 32-bit-only QuickTime C API, not the 64-bit-compatible QuickTime Kit, to write the movie.

Comment: The links you provided seem to be *exactly* what I am looking for. Thank you very much for the info.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the X11 portion of this question: You can use [XQueryPointer](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryPointer.html)'s child_return for similar functionality to WindowFromPont.  [XGetGeometry](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetGeometry.html) should get you the GetWindowRect information.