# Is there a way to enumerate the open windows on Mac and X11?

Tags: macos, x11, window-managers

Basically, I am looking for something like Win32's EnumChildWindows on Mac and X11, which takes a handle to a window and returns a list of its child windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For X11, look at the [xwininfo](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xwininfo/tree/) source to see how `xwininfo -children` works.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful and will lead me to creating the function I need. Also, as a note to anyone else reading this question, a solution for Mac can be found on the accepted answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869052/how-do-i-find-a-window-at-a-certain-point-on-the-screen-for-screenshot-screen-rec and the function itself looks like CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo. I haven't tested it but the documentation looks like it's roughly equivalent to a combination between EnumChildWindows, GetWindowRect, GetWindowText and more.